# Double color event fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I've been used full calendar for registering appointments.

But now, I have a problem: 
Can I set a double color for single event?
Because I've to register a "extra start time" to event but the color needs to be different.

Example:

If i have an event that starts at 10.pm , I need to do start that event at 8.pm but 2 hour of difference need to be different color.

Comment: are you looking to do this for the week/day view?

Comment: At the moment I'm working with weekagend view.
for more details:
I'm working with Angularjs and Fullcalendar v.2